# Matlab Clamped Spline

Tags: matlab, math, interpolation

I need to solve the question on the photo with the help of matlab What am I doing wrong? Are there some who can help? Very important to me.

```
clc;
clear;
format compact;
T=[0 3 5 8 13]
V=[0 225 383 623 993]
A=[75 77 80 74 72]
v_5=interp1(T,V,5);
a_5=interp1(T,A,5);
t_5=interp1(T,A,5);
x=0:3:13;
y=interp1(T,A,x,'spline');
plot(T,V,'o',x,y),title('speed vs distance ')
```

[image]

Comment: "Matlap"?? Typo maybe.

Comment: Look into the `spline()` function to complete the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously a homework and it is not how things work in SO. You should first take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking such questions. However, I will give you a hint (first part of the question) and I guess you will be fine working the whole thing out by yourself.

You need to use regression to be able to estimate some values between the given observations though interpolation.
The function `interp1` returns interpolated values of a 1-D function at specific query points using linear interpolation.

```
 vq = interp1(x,v,xq)
```

Vector x contains the sample points (Time in your case), and v contains the corresponding values, v(x) (distance or speed in your case). Vector xq contains the coordinates of the query points.

So you can find the position and speed of the car at `t=10` as follows:

```
Time = [0 3 5 8 13];
Distance =[0 225 383 623 993];
Speed = [75 77 80 74 72];
t_10 = 10;                              % the query point
d_10 = interp1(Time,Distance,t_10)      % find the distance at t=10
v_10 = interp1(Time,Speed,t_10)         % find the speed at t=10
```

It would result:

```
d_10 =

   771


v_10 =

   73.2000
```

and you can confirm this on a plot as well:

[image]

**Edit:**

For a cubic spline you need to replace the `interp1d` with `spline`. Check the documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html).

Comment: This does not look like a cubic spline to me.

Comment: Look at the `spline()` function.

Comment: The `spline` function is used to fit a spline onto data.

Comment: if you are replying to the SO, you should comment under his/her question. I  know what spline function does.

Comment: yes you are right this is my homework but I actually asked the question missing.I have to solve with clamped spline ı can't find any command in matlab related with clamped spline.Thank you so much again you make my day